# parsing xml from url

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, url

I want to parse an xml, but I can't find any good tutorials.

```
    import urllib.request
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

    with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/lastA.xml') as response:
    lasta = response.read()
```

What exactly is `lasta`. Is it still xml or a string or something else?

Comment: Indentation will be a problem for the last line.  That matters for Python.  It'll be a string that you need to parse into a DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest BeautifulSoup: [Python BeautifulSoup XML Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071696/python-beautifulsoup-xml-parsing) 
It has a bunch of helper methods that makes navigating a tree-structure (XML, or HTML) easier.

As to your question,  'lasta' is just a string, it hasn't been converted to XML yet. For downloading files over the internet, you may want to consider using the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.org/en/master/) package as that is recommended for high-level HTTP operations.