# XML Parsing help Python lxml, etree, or dom

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I've been beating myself trying to parse XML response from library documentation, but cannot determine a simple way to find the values I want.  I'll use any common library.

Sample XML response which is in string format:

```
<entry
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
       xmlns:s="http://dev.splunk.com/ns/rest"
       xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
  <title>search index</title>
  <id>https://localhost:8089/services/search/jobs/mysearch_02151949</id>
  <updated>2011-07-07T20:49:58.000-07:00</updated>
  <link href="/services/search/jobs/mysearch_02151949" rel="alternate"/>
  <published>2011-07-07T20:49:57.000-07:00</published>
  <link href="/services/search/jobs/mysearch_02151949/search.log" rel="search.log"/>
  <link href="/services/search/jobs/mysearch_02151949/events" rel="events"/>
  <link href="/services/search/jobs/mysearch_02151949/results" rel="results"/>
  <link href="/services/search/jobs/mysearch_02151949/results_preview" rel="results_preview"/>
  <link href="/services/search/jobs/mysearch_02151949/timeline" rel="timeline"/>
  <link href="/services/search/jobs/mysearch_02151949/summary" rel="summary"/>
  <link href="/services/search/jobs/mysearch_02151949/control" rel="control"/>
  <author>
    <name>admin</name>
  </author>
  <content type="text/xml">
    <s:dict>
      <s:key name="cursorTime">1969-12-31T16:00:00.000-08:00</s:key>
      <s:key name="delegate"></s:key>
      <s:key name="diskUsage">2174976</s:key>
      <s:key name="dispatchState">DONE</s:key>
      <s:key name="doneProgress">1.00000</s:key>
      <s:key name="dropCount">0</s:key>
      <s:key name="earliestTime">2011-07-07T11:18:08.000-07:00</s:key>
      <s:key name="eventAvailableCount">287</s:key>
      <s:key name="eventCount">287</s:key>
      <s:key name="eventFieldCount">6</s:key>
      <s:key name="eventIsStreaming">1</s:key>
      <s:key name="eventIsTruncated">0</s:key>
      <s:key name="eventSearch">search index</s:key>
      <s:key name="eventSorting">desc</s:key>
      <s:key name="isDone">1</s:key>
```

I've truncated the output and the two values I want are the text values for:

- name="isDone" (1)
- name="doneProgress" (1.00000)
- name="eventCount" (287)

How do I find these numeric values?

Comment: Have you looked at beautifulsoup4? I've had good luck with it. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071696/python-beautifulsoup-xml-parsing#4093940

Comment: I'm a big fan of BS4.  I just wanted an actual XML library to do the work, since it's integrating with Splunk which is XML-native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lxml` and `xpath`:

```
ns = {'s':"http://dev.splunk.com/ns/rest"}
print xml.xpath("//s:key[@name='isDone']/text()", namespaces=ns)
```

which will print `[1]`.  Full example:

```
xml = '''
<entry
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
       xmlns:s="http://dev.splunk.com/ns/rest"
       xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
  <title>search index</title>
  <id>https://localhost:8089/services/search/jobs/mysearch_02151949</id>
  <updated>2011-07-07T20:49:58.000-07:00</updated>
  <link href="/services/search/jobs/mysearch_02151949" rel="alternate"/>
  <published>2011-07-07T20:49:57.000-07:00</published>
  <link href="/services/search/jobs/mysearch_02151949/search.log" rel="search.log"/>
  <link href="/services/search/jobs/mysearch_02151949/events" rel="events"/>
  <link href="/services/search/jobs/mysearch_02151949/results" rel="results"/>
  <link href="/services/search/jobs/mysearch_02151949/results_preview" rel="results_preview"/>
  <link href="/services/search/jobs/mysearch_02151949/timeline" rel="timeline"/>
  <link href="/services/search/jobs/mysearch_02151949/summary" rel="summary"/>
  <link href="/services/search/jobs/mysearch_02151949/control" rel="control"/>
  <author>
    <name>admin</name>
  </author>
  <content type="text/xml">
    <s:dict>
      <s:key name="cursorTime">1969-12-31T16:00:00.000-08:00</s:key>
      <s:key name="delegate"></s:key>
      <s:key name="diskUsage">2174976</s:key>
      <s:key name="dispatchState">DONE</s:key>
      <s:key name="doneProgress">1.00000</s:key>
      <s:key name="dropCount">0</s:key>
      <s:key name="earliestTime">2011-07-07T11:18:08.000-07:00</s:key>
      <s:key name="eventAvailableCount">287</s:key>
      <s:key name="eventCount">287</s:key>
      <s:key name="eventFieldCount">6</s:key>
      <s:key name="eventIsStreaming">1</s:key>
      <s:key name="eventIsTruncated">0</s:key>
      <s:key name="eventSearch">search index</s:key>
      <s:key name="eventSorting">desc</s:key>
      <s:key name="isDone">1</s:key>
    </s:dict>
  </content>
</entry>
'''

from lxml import etree
from cStringIO import StringIO

xml = StringIO(xml)
xml = etree.parse(xml)
ns = {'s':"http://dev.splunk.com/ns/rest"}
print xml.xpath("//s:key[@name='isDone']/text()", namespaces=ns)
```

Comment: My source is already in string format, so I'm able to omit
`from cStringIO import StringIO`
`xml = StringIO(xml)`

I've tried using this:
`xml = etree.fromstring(xml)`
`ns = {'s':"http://dev.splunk.com/ns/rest"}`
`print xml.xpath("//s:key[@name='isDone']/text()", namespaces=ns)`
but now I get AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute xpath

Comment: Actually, it worked.  My AttributeError problem was unrelated.