# capture and remove beginning and end xml open and close tag with regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex, beautifulsoup

I have the following XML:

```
<data xmlns="">
<color>blue green</color>
<install>No</install>
<days>4</start>
</data>
```

I am looking to remove '', '' as well as remove the open and closing tags from a beautiful soup element.

The output should be:

```
Color: blue green, install: no, days: 4
```

here is what I've tried:

```
new = re.sub(r'(/>)</data>.+', '</data>', new)
```

I'm just learning how to regex, please forgive the noobness.

Comment: If available, try using a parser instead of regex. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071696/python-beautifulsoup-xml-parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, the results can be achieved using `BeautifulSoup`, instead of regex.

All you need to do is find the tag data. Then loop through `findChildren()`. This will allow you to capture the tag name and text.

**For example:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<data xmlns="">
<color>blue green</color>
<install>No</install>
<days>4</start>
</data>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml') 
data=soup.find('data')

results = []
for x in data.findChildren():
    results.append(f'{x.name}: {x.text.strip()}')

separator = ', '
print(separator.join(results))
```

**Output**

```
color: blue green, install: No, days: 4
```

Comment: Thank you @greg for the advise and the solution!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use regex to extract your XML, could use this:

```
import re

txt = """
</data>\<data xmlns="">
<color>blue green</color>
<install>No</install>
<days>4</start>
</data>
"""
x = re.findall("(?<=<)([^\/>]+)>(.+)(?=<)", txt)

result=[]
for i in range(len(x)):
    result.append(x[i][0] +': ' + x[i][1] )
print(', '.join(result))
```

**Output:**

```
color: blue green, install: No, days: 4
```

See https://regex101.com/r/Yqtnkx/1

It doesn't have good performance, but I hope it helps you.